# $wpdb is null even after 'global $wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I have seen almost all links but still I am unable to solve my problem.

I am getting $wpdb as `null`.

I am checking it like this. I am doing this in single.php file

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($wpdb);"</pre>";
```

I have checked about following files. That all are loaded.

1. wp-config.php
2. wp-load.php
3. wp-includes/wp-db.php

Please help me.

**EDIT**

I want to execute custom query like this.

```
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT forms.form_title, entries. *
        FROM wp_visual_form_builder_forms AS forms
        INNER JOIN wp_visual_form_builder_entries AS entries ON   entries.form_id = forms.form_id" ) );
```

this is not working.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling this code from?

Comment: From single.php, Inside template

Comment: Just to clarify: you are calling it from /wp-content/themes/[your theme name]/single.php? Which version of Wordpress are you using?

Comment: Ya you are right. I am using 3.5.2 version.

Comment: In which function are you trying to use `$wpdb`?

Comment: I have modified that file. there is custom hard coded. No function. Thats why I think its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), you will notice this passage:

```
Always use the global $wpdb variable. (Remember to globalize $wpdb before using it in any custom functions.)
```

It's not very clear but I think that means you cannot use `$wpdb` outside of a function. What I recommend you do is create a function in your theme's `functions.php` file, and call that function from the single.php file.